# Trouble Reading Sectors off of CD INT 13h AH=42H

Tags: assembly, bootloader

I have been trying to write a BootLoader that Reads the sectors off of a CD instead of a floppy and I have started out by just reading the first sector but It When I run it the Carry flag is still set and according to the documentation from here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH.3D42h%3a_Extended_Read_Sectors_From_Drive
That means it was unable to Read the sector from the Image Here is my full boot Code:

```
BITS   16

ORG  0x00

Start: jmp main


;Colors for text
%DEFINE TEAL 0x03
%DEFINE RED 0x04
%DEFINE PURPLE 0x05
COL: db 0
ROW:  db 0

;macro for print
%macro Print 2
    xor dx, dx
    mov dh, BYTE[ROW];puts the row into the dh register
    xor bx, bx
    mov bl, %2
    mov si, %1
    call cPrint


    mov ah, 0x02            ;set cursor pos
    mov bh, 0x00            ;page 00
    inc dh                  ;row 00
    mov dl, 0x00            ;col. 00    
    int 0x10

    mov BYTE[ROW], dh;saves the rows for the next time we need to print
%endmacro


cPrint:                   ; Routine: output string in SI to screen


 .top:
    ;Paramaters for Input 
    mov ah, 09h             ; Must be 9 to print color
    mov cx, 0x01            ;x position
    lodsb                   ; Get character from string
    test al, al
    je .done                ; If char is zero, end of string
    int 0x10                 ; Otherwise, print it

    mov ah, 0x02            ;set cursor position
    mov bh, 0x00            ;page
    inc dl      ;column
    int 0x10                ;changes the cursor position so the next char can be written at the new location
    jmp .top

 .done:
    ret

;clears the screen and sets the cursor position to the top left 
 clear:
    mov ah, 0x0F            ;get current video mode
    mov al, 0x00            ;reset register
    int 0x10                ;get video mode
    mov ah, 0x00            ;set video mode
    int 0x10                ;reset screen
    mov ah, 0x02            ;set cursor pos
    mov bh, 0x00            ;page 00
    mov dh, 0x00            ;row 00
    mov dl, 0x00            ;col. 00
    int 0x10                ;set pos
ret




Read_Extended_Sector:
    pusha
    xor ax, ax
    xor dx, dx
    xor bx, bx
    ;read in the sector


    .ForLoop:
        MOV DL,BYTE[CDDriveNumber]              ; Set it up again 
        MOV AH,42h                          ; Read from drive function 
        MOV SI,DiskAddressPacket            ; Load SI with address of the Disk Address Packet 
        INT 13h    
        jnc .Success


        Print Read_Sector_Error_MSG, PURPLE
        cli
        hlt

    .Success:
        Print READ_SUCCESS, TEAL
        cmp ah, Stage2
        jz .DONE
        Print FILE_NOT_FOUND, RED
        cli
        hlt
    .DONE:
    popa
ret


main:

    cli; disable interrupts
    mov ax, 0x07c0  ;adjust the segment registers
    mov ds, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov fs, ax


Create_Stack:
    xor ax, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp ,0x0FFFE
    sti ; enable interrupts

    call clear


    Print W_MSG, TEAL;prints the loading message in colour


    call Read_Extended_Sector; Reads the first sector of the drive 
    ;the read in data is stored in AH














cd_signature: db "CD001"        
cd_Version:   db 0x01
CDDriveNumber: db 80h

;Disk Address Packet


DiskAddressPacket:          db 16,0 
.SectorsToRead:             dw 1                              ; Number of sectors to read (read size of OS) 
.Offset:                    dw 0                              ; Offset :0000 
.Segment:                   dw 0200h                          ; Segment 0200
.End:                       dq 16                             ; Sector 16 or 10h on CD-ROM 



W_MSG: db "Loading Z-Boot...........", 0
Stage2: db "STAGE2 BIN"
Read_Sector_Error_MSG: db "Failed to read sector ......",0
READ_SUCCESS: db "Reading the first sector was a success .......",0
FILE_NOT_FOUND: db "Error, File not found......."
times 2046 - ($ - $$) db 0; padd out the rest of the file to 0
DW 0xAA55
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently I forgot to save the drive number after I set up the segments here:

```
Create_Stack:
    xor ax, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp ,0x0FFFE
    sti

    mov     [CDDriveNumber],dl
```

withought the drive number the function will not work. I am still new to this so maybe someone else can explain this in depth?

Comment: awesome, that's an exercise i've been thinking of doing one day. i hope you find more details on that and enrich the internet with your knowledge. other people went through that (bsd writers, grub writers, lilo writers...) and often have private newgroup exchange or mail exchanges about these stuff. but a lot of it is pre-popular-internet era and not as easily accessible as stackoverflow.

Comment: Just one warning: I saw buggy BIOSes that assumed that the ES register contains the "segment" from the disk access packet. You should set ES to 0200h to be compatible with such BIOSes.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Thanks for the warning I have am having another problem with finding the root directory could you take a look at it? It seems like you know a lot about this type of thing.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Almost forgot the link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949598/finding-the-start-of-the-root-directory-bootloader

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BIOS provides the number of drive it booted off in the `DL` register.  Drive `00h` is the first floppy drive, drive `01h` is the second. Drive `80h` is the first hard disk, and subsequent hard drives follow. When booting from a CD-ROM, and only when booting from a CD-ROM, the BIOS emulates the CD-ROM as if it were a hard disk. That's why you can use the `INT 13h, AX=42` Extended Read BIOS call to read it. The drive number that BIOS assigns the emulated CD-ROM varies from system to system so you can't hard code it.